# Audio interface from MIDI Keyboard to Logic Pro X on Mac Mini

Tags: mac, audio, ui, logic

How do I connect my MIDI keyboard using MIDI to Thunderbolt interface with zero latency which is compatible with Logic Pro X? I'm aware of MIDI to USB interface but Thunderbolt is much faster. Otherwise, would I need to purchase an audio box?

Comment: Thunderbolt has higher bandwidth, but the latency introduced by USB is effectively zero. I wouldn't be concerned with using it.

Comment: Will my Mbox 2 work with Logic Pro X on my newly purchased Mac mini (still being shipped)? According to the following YouTube video it works:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dlPez_u72lw   (go straight to 1:48)

Comment: I'm going to guess so, though the drivers haven't been updated in forever. Since you've already got it I'd wait and see if you can get it to work, and if not, post a question.